# NGINX Not Loading Resources for Second Server

Tags: asp.net, linux, nginx, phoenix-framework

I'm new to NGINX (well hosting in general), so please excuse my ignorance. I have a Phoenix web app running on localhost:4000 and an ASP.NET web app running on localhost:5123. I'm trying to utilize NGINX to create a reverse proxy so that either web app can be accessed from the same domain. My NGINX config file contains the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
  }

  location /test {
    rewrite /test(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5123;
  }
}
```

I'm able to access server 1 on `example.com/` and server 2 on `example.com/test`, however, server 2 is not able to load its own css, javascript and image files. Is there a way to ensure server 1 and server 2 utilize their own resources via the NGINX config setup?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way. There are some lines missing on your second service:

Replace...

```
location /test {
    rewrite /test(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5123;
}
```

with...

```
location /test {
    rewrite                /test/(.*) /$1 break;
    rewrite                ^/test$ /test/ permanent;
    proxy_pass             http://localhost:5123/;
    proxy_redirect         / /test/;
    proxy_set_header       Host $host;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to achieve this. Long time ago I used this configuration to implement an etherpad-service on my server. That time I had not the option to use a subdomain. Anyway - using a subdomain for your second service would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made your edits and reloaded the nginx service but I don't see any changes. The resources are still missing from `/test`.

Comment: @jsonkenl Have you restartet your browser, too? (Maybe the site is still cached by the browser)

Comment: Yes, I even opened up a fresh instance of Firefox (currently using Chrome) and same issue.

Comment: What are the types of your pathes inside your html? Are they relative or absolute?

Comment: Unless it's pulling from a CDN, they are all relative. Errors in the browser console show it's trying to fetch resources at the root location for server 1, but is erroring out since those resources do not exist at that location.

Comment: Ok. Last try: Have you a slash behind '/test' in your first rewrite rule like me? In your original code this slash is missing. You should have this slash if you copied my hole code.

Comment: Yes, I checked every character and it matched yours. I appreciate the effort, I'll try to use a subdomain instead.